# Unable to get exact WPF DataGrid embedded control type From DataGridTemplateColumn

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid, wpf-4.0

```
public void MouseSingleClickEditable(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{

    if ((!datagrid.HasItems) || datagrid.SelectedIndex < 0) return;

    DataGridColumn clmn = datagrid.CurrentColumn;
    if (clmn != null)
    {
        String columnType = clmn.GetType().Name;

            switch (columnType)
            {
                case "DataGridTemplateColumn":
                case "DataGridCheckBoxColumn":
                    row = (DataGridRow)datagrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(datagrid.Items[datagrid.SelectedIndex]);
                    if (!row.IsEditing)
                    {

                        datagrid.IsReadOnly = false;
                        datagrid.BeginEdit();
                    }

                    break;
                default:
                    break;
        }
    }
}
```

I have 2 DatePickers, Checkbox and a combobox in my WPF Datagrid but while geeting the column type I am getting it only as DataGridTemplateColumn instead of type DataGridDatePickerColumn or DataGridComboboxColumn. How to extract the exact type of Control from the DataGridTemplateColumn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   public void MouseSingleClickEditable(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
            var datagrid = new DataGrid();
            if ((!datagrid.HasItems) || datagrid.SelectedIndex < 0) return;

            DataGridColumn clmn = datagrid.CurrentColumn;
            if (clmn != null) {
                if (clmn is DataGridCheckBoxColumn) {
                    //do something
                } else if (clmn is DataGridTemplateColumn) {
                    var templateColumn = (DataGridTemplateColumn)clmn;

                    var rootControlOfCellTemplate = templateColumn.CellTemplate.LoadContent();
                    var rootControlOfCellEditingTemplate = templateColumn.CellEditingTemplate.LoadContent();
                    // you can now check for types of the template. CellEditingTemplate is for template in edit mode, and CellTemplate for "non-edit" mode
                    // for example
                    if (rootControlOfCellTemplate is Button) {
                        //do something
                    }
                    if (rootControlOfCellEditingTemplate is DatePicker) {
                        //do something
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Note how I check for types. Normally you should do it like this, not by hard-coded strings.

Comment: Thanks for your response but its showing warning message as "The given expression is never of the provided (System.Windows.Controls.DatePicker)type "

Comment: Thanks again to you, But here the VisualTree is returning null for me. So it is raising null reference exception. Anything else from my part I have to look into ?

Comment: Did you set CellTemplate and/or CellEditingTemplate for your DataGridTemplateColumn?

Comment: Yes For Combobox I have set CellTemplate and For DatePicker I have set bot CellTemplate aswell as CellEditingTemplate in XAML design part.

Comment: Apparently, this is known behaviour. I changed the code again. Try it now.